# When do I have to use a friend function rather than a member function?

Tags: c++, class, friend

Can any body give me one condition when a friend function is definitely better than a member function? Or simply some reasons why we may use a friend function rather than a member function. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html not sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

### Stream operations.

Friend functions are well suited to operator overloads.

For an operator like an inserter `<<` or extractor `>>`, the stream object appears on the left-hand side so it cannot be a member. But, arguably such a function should seldom be a friend because it should be built on a public inspection or initialization interface.

---

### Binary operations.

Binary operators, especially commutative ones provide a more interesting case. If implemented as a member function, the overload is dispatched according to member lookup using the LHS. A friend function would use argument-dependent lookup with both the LHS and RHS treated equally.

This is important if conversions are allowed. If I have a `string` class which implicitly converts from a `char const *` C-style string, then `string string::operator+(string)` wouldn't be found for the expression `"x" + str` but the `friend string operator+(string, string)` would. By the way, `std::string` conforms to this example and that's why it uses non-member operators.

---

### Interfaces spanning more than your classes.

Another case is when you want something which can't be a member because it's defined over classes you don't control, or non-class types. Maybe it's just a no-op when applied to "something random," yet still make sense as such. For example, I defined such a function `flush` which signals end of input and propagates through a parser. The meaning is well-defined across many things that I didn't implement.

Answer (score 2):

One case (probably typical case) is that when you tries to overload the `<<` operator to print members of your class. You simply cannot overload it as a `member function` since the first parameter must be an object of `ostream`. You have to use the `friend` function.

According to Scott Myers's Effective C++ Item23:

> Prefer non-member non-friend functions to member functions. Doing so increases encapsulation, packaging flexibility, and functional extensibility.

Comment: not sure how the Meyers quote is relevant when he is talking specifically about NON-friends...?

Answer (score 0):

When you are overloading operators that use parameters from the same class , then you use member functions. Also , for defining the behaviour of the class , u use member functions.
Friend functions are used to overload operators that use parameters of different classes,

for example the stream operators,
`cout << 2`
in this case, cout is an object of the ostream class and 2 a member of int class.

In this case you would use friend functions, which are non member functions , that allow you to use objects of other classes as well when the operator is being used. 
stream insertion operator and stream extraction operator are examples.

Answer (score 0):

One of the cornerstones of object-oriented design is that of objects interacting by sending messages.  In order to send a message (in this case, invoke a member function) an object must have a ‘link’ to the target object.  That link is formed by building in an association between the two classes as part of the type’s definition.

In a peer-to-peer relationship either object may invoke the operations on the other.  That is, the relationship is bi-directional.

If the association is bi-directional, then both classes need pointers. The problems come when you have to bind the objects together.  The problem is which object gets built first?  If both classes need a reference to the other in their constructors to work there is a cyclic dependency.

Probably the most elegant approach is to create a free function that binds the two objects together.  The 'bind' function is made a friend of both classes to allow the connection of their pointers (without otherwise exposing them):

```
class CameraStabiliser;

class UI
{
private:
  CameraStabiliser* pStabiliser;

public:
  UI() : pStabiliser(NULL) {}
  void inPosition();

  friend void bind(UI& ui, CameraStabiliser& cs);
};


class CameraStabiliser
{
private:
  UI* pUI;

public:
  CameraStabiliser() : pUI(NULL) {}
  void moveTo(Position pos);

  friend void bind(UI& ui, CameraStabiliser& cs);
};


void bind(UI& ui, CameraStabiliser& cs)
{
  ui.pStabiliser = &cs;
  cs.pUI = &ui;
}


int main()
{
  UI console;
  CameraStabiliser stabiliser;

  bind(console, stabiliser);
}
```